# Nunit 3.6.1 testcase with category: category not available in testcontext

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have noticed that when using a testcase instead of a test, the category of the test is not available through the testcontext. So lets view some code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FormTests : BrowserTests
{
    [TestCase("/some-url/", FormType.ContactForm), Category("form")]
    [TestCase("/some-other-url/", FormType.ContactForm), Category("form")]
    public void AssertFormIsSubmittable(string url, FormType formType)
    {
        Browser.OpenPage($"{BaseUrl}{url}", true);
        Browser.Action(FormActions.EnterFormFields(formType));
        Browser.Action(FormActions.Submit());

        var isSuccesfullySubmitted = Browser.Verify(FormState.IsSubmitted());
        Assert.IsTrue(isSuccesfullySubmitted);
    }

    [Test, Category("form")]
    public void FunctionToTestIfCategoryIsWorking()
    {
        Browser.OpenPage($"{BaseUrl}", true);
        Browser.Action(FormActions.EnterFormFields(FormType.ContactForm));
        Browser.Action(FormActions.Submit());

        var isSuccesfullySubmitted = Browser.Verify(FormState.IsSubmitted());
        Assert.IsTrue(isSuccesfullySubmitted);
    }
}
```

When running the AssertFormIsSubmittable (with the testcases), within the BrowserTests base class, when I execute:`var category = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Category");` the result is null.

When i execute FunctionToTestIfCategoryIsWorking, the same line of code has "form" as a result. That's the expected result. Somehow, when using a TestCase, it doesn't work anymore.

I tried to change the attributes to:

```
[TestCase("/some-url/", FormType.ContactForm)]
[TestCase("/some-other-url/", FormType.ContactForm)]
[Category("form")]
```

And:

```
[Category("form")]
[TestCase("/some-url/", FormType.ContactForm)]
[TestCase("/some-other-url/", FormType.ContactForm)]
```

And:

```
[Test, Category("form")]
[TestCase("/some-url/", FormType.ContactForm)]
[TestCase("/some-other-url/", FormType.ContactForm)]
```

All with the same result. I looked for people experiencing the same issue, but i found no loads. And i looked for known-issues and bugs on https://github.com/nunit/nunit but found nothing that seemed relevant.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community, Update 3 on a Windows 7 Enterprise machine. I have the Nunit 3 Test Adapter Visual Studio extension installed.

Is there anything I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated of course :)

Comment: this is likely just a bug in NUnit. Can you please submit it there and we can discuss/confirm on GitHub. When we construct tests, TestCase works a bit different, so that is likely where the issue is. https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues

Comment: Submitted on GitHub: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2107